# How to properly return value from a data inside the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, return

Im new to javascript and started to learn amazing stuff from it. As the code below how can I be able to return the value of `index` inside `getData().then(data => {`. `getData` function has json response values.

```
subPatternStart() {
  getData().then(data => {
    var patternStart = 1525750500000;
    var index = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if ( patternStart >= data[i].time && patternStart < data[i+1].time ) {
        //...somecode
      }
    }
    console.log("Index:" , index);
  })
}
```

What I want to achieve is that when I call this function I should ONLY get the value of index, which in this case the console log value is equivalent into `1`.

I have this in my render method.

```
render() {
  index={this.subPatternStart()}
}
```

In this simple code, it returns the exact value in the render method, and I want to do something like this.

```
subPatternStart() {
  var patternStart = 1;
  return patternStart;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the state of the component with the value you get from `getData`. Then React can update it self and render the page. For example

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      index: 0
    }
  }

  subPatternStart() {
    getData().then(data => {
      var patternStart = 1525750500000;
      var index = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (patternStart >= data[i].time && patternStart < data[i + 1].time) {
          //...somecode
        }
      }
      this.setState({
        index: index
      });
    })
  }
  render() {
    index =  this.state.index
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I log `this.setState({ index: index })`, its undefined. And I get an empty result in `this.state.index`

Comment: Ill accept this as answer as this is what Im using. This was easy to implement compare to the other solution as newbie. I might need to study more to implement the other answer. Thanks Ron for this!

Comment: modified the rendered value. Edited one is what im using that works.

Answer (score 0):

the function `subPatternStart` calls an async function `getData` so you need to use either `callback` or `promises` to get data in return.

### 1. Using Callbacks

```
subPatternStart(callbackFunction) {
        getData().then(data => {
            var patternStart = 1525750500000;
            var index = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (patternStart >= data[i].time && patternStart < data[i + 1].time) {
                    //...somecode
                }
            }
            console.log("Index:", index);
            callbackFunction(index);
        })
    }

// calling the function
render() {
    var index;
    this.subPatternStart((i) => { index = i })
}
```

### 2. Using Promises

```
subPatternStart(callbackFunction) {
    var promise = new Promise(resolve => {
        getData().then(data => {
            var patternStart = 1525750500000;
            var index = 0;

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (patternStart >= data[i].time && patternStart < data[i + 1].time) {
                    //...somecode
                }
            }
            console.log("Index:", index);
            resolve(index);
        })
    })
    return promise;
}


// calling the function
async render() {
    index = await this.subPatternStart();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response, I did exactly code you have, and it giving me `TypeError: callbackFunction is not a function`.

Comment: is there special dependencies for `async`? As im getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined`

Comment: for implementation of async/await on react you can read this https://medium.com/@kkomaz/react-to-async-await-553c43f243e2

Comment: use `transform-runtime` plugin to remove the `regeneratorRumtime` error

Comment: how can I log the result of the function? this doesnt seems proper `console.log(this.subPatternStart((i) => { index = i }))`

Comment: `this.subPatternStart((i) => { console.log("Index:", i); index = i; });`

Comment: thats perfect! Sorry for asking a lot. I tried to do it myself but im getting `unexpected token` on `this` in my actual code in render. ```
  render() {
    var trendstartdate;
    let element = this.state.data? <Chart 
        //trendstartdate={ this.subPatternStart}
        this.subPatternStart((i) => { trendstartdate = i; })
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172665/discussion-between-john-rey-tanquinco-and-tech-hawk).